# What's the different between HRESULT E_FAIL error of 0x80004005 and 0x80000008?

Tags: c++, shell-extensions, hresult

i'm a bit confused,
i've checked WinError.h and saw 2 E_FAIL declerations:

```
//
// MessageId: E_FAIL
//
// MessageText:
//
// Unspecified error
//
#define E_FAIL                           _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x80000008L)

//
// MessageId: E_FAIL
//
// MessageText:
//
// Unspecified error
//
#define E_FAIL                           _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x80004005L)
```

One issue that I've encountered, is that i'm implementing namespace extensions, and when opening a file that doesnt exist, i get the following:

when returning 0x80000008 - i get "Unspecified error"

when returning 0x80004005 - i get the **desired** behavior "The file name is not valid."

So what should i use? what's the difference?
thanks

Comment: And this is why trying to understand code with zero context doesn't work!!

Comment: uhm, i've added context - under open file dialog.

Comment: No, what I mean is, you missed the `#if` `#else` and considered only the definitions in isolation. The context — that is, the surrounding code — turned out to be a crucial part of answering the question (in fact, _the_ answer!) and this is very often the case. So there's a lesson to be learnt from it. :)

Comment: I understand :) well, as i answered in your answer - i understand now.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are defined in a conditional block.

The second is defined when:

```
#if defined(_WIN32) && !defined(_MAC)
```

and the first when:

```
#else
```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: ah, i've missed that (i'm moving it to managed C# code).
what does the "_MAC" macro stands for?

Which set of macros should i use if i'm migrating it to C# then?

Comment: @ArielB: The same ones? It's entirely up to you. I have no knowledge of what your migration involves or requires...

Comment: also the first comment - thanks :)
it's actually a 3rd party and very complex code that we have, and i found out the an incorrect E_FAIL was used. so i just wanted to be sure why.

anyway - it represents MAC OS - so i need the other macros.

http://ftp.icpdas.com/pub/beta_version/VHM/wince600/at91sam9g45m10ek_armv4i/cesysgen/sdk/inc/rpc.h